# Why the text indicated on figure is being cut?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm a newbie here and I have a problem with my graphic. It is not complete because my text that indicate each function on the plane is being cut. What do I need to do?

[image: Graph result]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
%definição do comportamento dos eixos
\begin{axis}[axis lines = center, axis line style={latex-latex}]
%definição das funções
    \addplot[mark=none, line width = 0.5pt]{x} node[pos=1,below] {$y = x$}; %função principal
    \addplot[mark=none, dotted]{x+1} node[pos=1,below] {$y = x+1$};
    \addplot[mark=none, dotted]{x-1} node[pos=1,below] {$y = x-1$};
    \addplot[mark=none, dotted]{(x+2} node[pos=1,below] {$y = x+2$};
    \addplot[mark=none, dotted]{(x-2} node[pos=1,below] {$y = x-2$};
%definição das legendas e pontos
    \addplot [mark=*,nodes near coords,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic]
    table[meta=label] {
    x   y   label
    1   1   $P_1$
    3   3   $P_2$
    2   4   $P_3$
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the option `clip=false` in the `axis` definition; I changed also all the nodes position to `right` in order to show better the corresponding function.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
%definição do comportamento dos eixos
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = center,
axis line style={latex-latex},
clip=false]
%definição das funções
    \addplot[mark=none, line width = 0.5pt]{x} node[pos=1,right] {$y = x$}; %função principal
    \addplot[mark=none, dotted]{x+1} node[pos=1,right] {$y = x+1$};
    \addplot[mark=none, dotted]{x-1} node[pos=1,right] {$y = x-1$};
    \addplot[mark=none, dotted]{(x+2} node[pos=1,right] {$y = x+2$};
    \addplot[mark=none, dotted]{(x-2} node[pos=1,right] {$y = x-2$};
%definição das legendas e pontos
    \addplot [mark=*,nodes near coords,only marks,point meta=explicit symbolic]
    table[meta=label] {
    x   y   label
    1   1   $P_1$
    3   3   $P_2$
    2   4   $P_3$
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

That produces:
[image]